# How to get text from span tag in Python

Tags: python, html

I have a python code and I don't use a function (just to inform you), which needs to copy only the text between  TEXT , but what I'm getting is just NONE. I used:

```
email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]').click()

email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')

email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]').click()
```

[enter image description here][1]

[enter image description here][2]

I am new to Python, so if someone can explain to me how I do it and show the code already made, I will be grateful, because my goal here is to learn and not just copy and paste, understand?

I need to copy the emails that are inside that , as they change according to each access to the page.

NOTE: I have already researched the site and it even has something similar, but it is not the way I understand and program it. They are useless!

Examples
[Code]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2CuH.png
[Site]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmgnn.png

Answer (score 0):

```py
email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]').click()

email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')

email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]').click()
```

The first time you create `email`, it contains `None`, because that's what `.click()` is obviously returning (in fact, it's returning nothing, which is converted by Python to None). Then, you overwrite `email` with the actual element object, but overwrite it a second time with `None`. What you should do is, get the element, `.click()` it, get the email into another variable, and `.click()` it again:

```py
email_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
email_element.click()
email = email_element.text
email_element.click()
print(email)
```

Comment: Thanks, with your help, I put the .text at the end of the code and it worked! Thank you very much...

Stayed:
email = driver.find_element_by_xpath ('// * [@ id = "email"]'). text